# How to exclude Ie9 or higher version from the test?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I added the following javascript to the page because when the the text is to long, some dropdownlists do not displays the whole content in IE.

```
$(".dropdown").mousedown(function () {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Now that I've fixed that problem, I just realize that IE9 does not have that problem. So how do I exclude IE9 or highier version from the above test?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You shouldn't do browser-testing at all. Use *feature detection* instead.

Comment: Load your script file within conditional comments.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 9) {
    // your code here for IE < 9
}
```

**UPDATE**

`$.browser` is deprecated.

One way to make sure your code runs only on `IE` < 9, is by using conditional statements.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="path-to-js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard : wow, Never realized that. Thanks, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe do this in the HEAD of your page:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.browser` has another property named version, use it to detect which version is being used.

```
console.log($.browser.version)
```

You really shouldn't be using `$.browser` at all though, it is gone in the next version of jQuery (1.9 and 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) > 9) {
    //exclude
}
```

And here is the same method in pure Javascript:

```
<script>

    function getIEVersion() {
        var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.test(ua) != null)
                rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
        }
        return rv;
    }


    function checkVersion() {
        var ver = getIEVersion();

        if ( ver != -1 ) {
            if (ver > 9.0) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }

    checkVersion();

</script>
```

But the best way is to not use UA Sniffing, instead use feature detection like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).